# Cannot catch NetworkImageLoadException when Image.network() failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I use Image.network() to show image from URL
this is how I use it

```
Image image = Image.network(
      _auth.currentUser!.photoURL!,
      width: 100.getWidth(context),
      height: 100.getWidth(context),
      frameBuilder: (context, child, frame, wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
        return wasSynchronouslyLoaded
            ? child
            : _profileImagePlaceholder(context);
      },
      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
        return loadingProgress == null
            ? child
            : _profileImagePlaceholder(context);
      },
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        return _profileImagePlaceholder(context);
      },
    );
```

But even when I set errorBuilder or even wrap the whole thing with try/catch
This `NetworkImageLoadException` still show

Full Exception

```
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,


When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:99:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
...

Image provider:
  NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/biddee-co.appspot.com/o/profiles%2FdefaultProfile.png?alt=media&token=a4a99031-aabd-4597-b075-77ecb2d3e594",
  scale: 1.0)
Image key:
  NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/biddee-co.appspot.com/o/profiles%2FdefaultProfile.png?alt=media&token=a4a99031-aabd-4597-b075-77ecb2d3e594",
  scale: 1.0)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. Even try/catch doesn't do anything and the app pauses because of "uncaught exception".

Comment: How do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, what fixed it in production code was to add a listener in the image resolve with a `onError`:

```dart
final image = Image.network(
  // Properties.
  errorBuilder: // ...,
);
image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty).addListener(
      ImageStreamListener(
        (_, __) { /* You can do something when the image is loaded. */ },
        onError: (_, __) {
          // Evict the object from the cache to retry to fetch it the next
          // time this widget is built.
          imageCache.evict(image.image);
        },
      ),
    );
```

While this works fine in debug / prod, in the tests where I used `HttpOverrides.runZoned()` with a client that always returns 404, the tests were always failing with an uncaught NetworkImageLoadException.

The fix was to listen to FlutterError at the beginning of the test and only throw if the exception caught was not a `NetworkImageLoadException`.

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FlutterError.onError = (details) {
  if (details.exception is! NetworkImageLoadException) throw details.exception;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these would work for me with the current release of Flutter. This is what worked for me.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
...
final String url;
...
class _WebIconState extends State<WebIcon> {
  late Widget imgWidget;
  late bool loaded;

  @override
  void initState() {
    imgWidget = SizedBox.shrink();
    loaded = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(widget.url);
    if (uri == null) {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
    if (!loaded) {
      () async {
        Response resp = await get(uri);
        if (resp.statusCode >= 200 &&
            resp.statusCode < 300 &&
            resp.headers["content-type"] is String &&
            resp.headers["content-type"]!.contains("image")) {
          setState(() {
            imgWidget = Image.memory(resp.bodyBytes);
            loaded = true;
          });
        }

        log("Loaded ${widget.url}");
      }();
    }

    return imgWidget;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ErrorBuilder for that

```
Image.network('Your image url...',
    errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        return Text('Error');
    },
),
```

Find out Documentation [from here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html)

Comment: I already did that as I mentioned and it still gives the Exception

Answer (score 0):

I tried also cached_network_image package and also try catch. But I couldn't find the solution. Then I made a basic implementation. I have small pictures so this solution works for me for now.

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  Map<String, Image?> imageDict = {};
  String name;
  String? profilepiclink;

  Future<Image?> fetchImage() async {
    if (imageDict[name] != null) {
      return imageDict[name];
    } else {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(profilepiclink!));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
        Image pic = Image.memory(response.bodyBytes);
        imageDict[name] = pic;
        return pic;
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then throw an exception.
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<Widget> _displayProfilePic() async {
    if (profilepiclink != null) {
      Image? profilPic = await fetchImage();

      return Container(
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: profilPic ?? const Icon(Icons.person),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle));
    }
    return const SizedBox(width: 30, child: Icon(Icons.person));
  }

  var image = FutureBuilder<Widget>(
            future: _displayProfilePic(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return snapshot.data!;
              }
              return const Icon(Icons.person);
           })
```

Answer (score -1):

in **package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart**

```dart
if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok) {
    // The network may be only temporarily unavailable, or the file will be
    // added on the server later. Avoid having future calls to resolve
    // fail to check the network again.
    await response.drain<List<int>>();
    throw image_provider.NetworkImageLoadException(statusCode: response.statusCode, uri: resolved);
}
```

That comment is what cause exception.

*The network may be only temporarily unavailable, or the file will be added on the server later. **Avoid** having future calls to resolve fail to check the network again.*