# Fail to load network image from firebase(statusCode:403 ,Type (NetworkImageLoadException))

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Flutter and I trying to load the user profile image using the NetworkImage ()into the user profile. However, it sometime will fail to catch the image from the network.After i check, the image are still inside the firestorge.How can i load it without this error again? (statusCode:403 ,Type (NetworkImageLoadException))

> NetworkImageLoadException (HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recipe-collector-fd10f.appspot.com/o/nomfoto-16:26:57:April8.jpg?alt=media)

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Authen/Google_SignIn.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Data/Model/recipeModel.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Data/Model/userModel.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Profile/AboutUs.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Profile/userManualPage.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Profile/userManual_Model.dart';
import '../Authen/InfoPage.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/globalVariable.dart' as globals;

import '../globalVariable.dart';

RecipeModel recipeModel = new RecipeModel();

// To calculate the total recipe created that user
int filterData(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  var documentCount = 0;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data!.documents;
  docs.forEach((doc) {
    documentCount++;
  });
  recipeModel.total_recipe = documentCount;
  return recipeModel.total_recipe;
}

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({super.key});

  @override
  State<Profile> createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
 
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  CollectionReference usersCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Profile',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
          elevation: 10,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: usersCollection.document(user.email).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
              if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Column(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 66, 66),
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              offset: Offset(0, 0))
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Stack(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 225,
                            width: displayWidth(context) * 0.8,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 1,
                              right: 1,
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Hero(
                                  tag: 'Profile',
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 16,
                                        right: 16,
                                        top: 16,
                                        bottom: 5),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: displayWidth(context) * 0.12,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        //  Image.memory(
                                        // decodedImage
                                        "${streamSnapshot.data!['photoUrl']}" +
                                            '?alt=media',
                                        // "${globals.user.photoUrl}"+
                                        //     '?alt=media',
                                      ),
                                      //AssetImage('assets/0314yuqi.jpg'),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "${streamSnapshot.data!['username']}",
                                    //"${globals.user.username}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.045,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "${streamSnapshot.data!['email']}",
                                    // "${globals.user.email}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.035,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                              top: 185,
                              left: 95,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 80,
                                width: 135,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219,
                                      219), //background color with opacity
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 66, 66),
                                        blurRadius: 15.0,
                                        offset: Offset(7, 8))
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Total Recipes",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize:
                                                  displayWidth(context) * 0.03,
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 51, 44, 25))),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 5,
                                      ),
                                      StreamBuilder(
                                          stream: db
                                              .collection('colrecipes')
                                              .snapshots(),
                                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                                              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>
                                                  snapshot) {
                                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                              return Center(
                                                child:
                                                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                              );
                                            }
                                            //call the total recipe created that user
                                            int i = filterData(snapshot);
                                            //print(recipeModel.total_recipe);
                                            return Text(
                                              "${recipeModel.total_recipe}",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize:
                                                      displayWidth(context) *
                                                          0.08,
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 51, 44, 25),
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                            );
                                          })
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            "INFO",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.045,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          )),
                    ),
                    ListView(
                      primary: false,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                side: BorderSide.none),
                            elevation: 15,
                            shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 66, 66),
                            child: ListTile(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide.none,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(50), //<-- SEE HERE
                                ),
                                tileColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                                leading: Icon(
                                  Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  "About Us",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.045,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => AboutUs()));
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                side: BorderSide.none),
                            elevation: 15,
                            shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 66, 66),
                            child: ListTile(
                                tileColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                                leading: Icon(
                                  Icons.help_outline_rounded,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                ),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide.none,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(50), //<-- SEE HERE
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  "Help",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.045,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  //     builder: (context) => userManualInfo(index: index, UserManual:UserManualData,)));
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219,
                                    219), //background color with opacity
                                // boxShadow: [
                                //   BoxShadow(
                                //       color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 66, 66),
                                //       blurRadius: 15.0,
                                //       offset: Offset(7, ))
                                // ],
                              ),
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: displayHeight(context) * 0.065,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                          RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  )),
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () => signOutUser().then((value) {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              MyliquidSwipe()),
                                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                                }),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Log Out',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.045,
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            })


        );


  }
}

double displayWidth(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint('Width = ' + displaySize(context).width.toString());
  return displaySize(context).width;
}

Size displaySize(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint('Size = ' + MediaQuery.of(context).size.toString());
  return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
}

double displayHeight(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint('Height = ' + displaySize(context).height.toString());
  return displaySize(context).height;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044951/cannot-catch-networkimageloadexception-when-image-network-failed